# High lighting a word in vim/bash

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, highlighting

[image]

While I was working on the terminal (mac os)
I pressed wrong combo then the 'def' word highlightend. I found it is very useful.

How to turn on and turn off highlight on a word? (shortcut key, no command or script please)

Answer (score 1):

You probably hit `*` or `#`, which searches for the word currently below the cursor and moves the cursor to the the next/previous match.

This also highlights all matches when `hlsearch` is set.

Turn off highlighting:

```
:noh
```

See here: [Highlight all occurrence of a selected word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431184/highlight-all-occurrence-of-a-selected-word)